# What are features of oops?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, break

The details of the project is to get the solution of oops features from the above statement.

I have expected some related solutions for the above question.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

features of OOP's are:
Inheritance.
Encapsulation.
Abstraction.
Polymorphism.
Method Overriding.
Method Overloading.
Objects.
Classes.